# Multiple clauses in one check constraint?

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, postgresql-8.4

I'm trying to get multiple clauses in one check constraint, separated by an `OR`:

```
check (stop>start or stop = NULL)
```

where start and stop are timestamp fields. So, `stop` can be left empty, but if it's specified, it has to be later than `start`.

Am I getting this entirely wrong? I haven't found anything on timestamp comparisons or if `OR` is allowed in check constraints.

This is in postgres 8.4.8.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `stop IS NULL`, not `stop = NULL`.

Comment: You should never use `value = NULL` nor `value <> NULL`, not even `NULL = NULL`. They will never evaluate to `True`.

Comment: Neither they evaluate to `false` ;-) They evaluate to `null`.

Answer (score 8):

This is allowed, but:

- `stop = NULL` is meaningless; you mean `stop IS NULL`.
- there's no need to specify `OR stop IS NULL` anyway, because check constraints only forbid something from being "false", and `stop > start` will be "null" (neither "true" nor "false") if `stop` is null.

For more information about check constraints, see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/ddl-constraints.html.

> It should be noted that a check constraint is satisfied if the check expression evaluates to true or the null value.

Comment: Yes, but the OP wants `stop` to be either `>start` or `NULL`.

Comment: @ypercube: Sorry, but you must have misunderstood what I wrote? My point is that `CHECK(stop > start)` is equivalent to `CHECK(stop > start OR stop IS NULL)`.